# How to add a link_to phone number with wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I would like to insert (in a wicked pdf) a link to a phone number like :

```
<a href="tel:<%= @user.phone %>"><%= @user.phone %></a>
```

Comment: When I click on the link in my PDF, wicked pdf return file:///...../number_phone